# Learning to translate the Shulchan Aruch

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, shulchan-aruch

How can I get good at translating the Shulchan Aruch? Due to the fact that a lot of the words are more of a Rabbinic Hebrew rather then a Modern Hebrew, it's harder to translate without an English-Hebrew Dictionary. Can y'all give me some advice on how I can improve my Shulchan Aruch reading skills?

Comment: What's wrong with sitting there with a dictionary as you described and working hard?

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch was written as a summary of the author's Beis Yosef, and assumes familiarity with the subject matter. If you want practical halacha, you are better off with a modern sefer that deals with modern situations. If you want to build skills, you would be better off starting with gemara. Without a basic familiarity with Talmudic methodology, it isn't possible to truly grasp the Shulchan Aruch's intent even with a translation.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ohr Olam Mishnah Berurah](http://ohr-olam.org/mishnah-berurah/) is an excellent translation of Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim including Mishna Brura. Learning a few *perakim* there will familiarize you with the vocabulary of Shulchan Aruch. You can then use it as a reference for when you get stuck on specific expressions or words.

You might also find a dictionary of abbreviations (e.g., [here](https://www.nehora.com/products/Thesaurus-of-Hebrew-Abbreviations-%28Hebrew%29-Otzar-Rashei-Tevot-----%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%252d%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%93%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9F.html) but there are many of them) helpful since SA and its commentaries are full of it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the [**Kitzur** Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch?lang=bi) first, especially the [Kleinman Edition](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/KSA1.html) from ArtScroll with an elucidated English translation. That should introduce you to some basic terms repeated throughout the regular Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Thanks. But I was referring more to Yoreh De'ah, Choshen Mishpat and E"h @ezra

Comment: @Moshe Nu? And the Kitzur does not touch on those topics?

Comment: He does. Just not in any way that'll help me translate independently Shulchan Aruch. @ezra

Comment: @Moshe Please note that bits and pieces are already translated on Sefaria and Wikisource. You might start with that.